# es6 map/set iterate from certain item (backwards)

Tags: dictionary, set, ecmascript-6

Beginner here, 
I'm a bit lost with es6 **set**, **map** and generators.

How can I select an item in a map, then iterate backwards from that point on effectively? Preferably without going through the whole set/map.

```
let v = myMap.get('key')
```

so, from 'v' to the beginning of the map (backwards)?

thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a set of iteration helpers and then compound to create the effect you want:

```
/* iterTo iterates the iterable from the start and up to (inclusive) key is found.
The function "understands" the Map type when comparing keys as well as
any other iterables where the value itself is the key to match. */
function* iterTo(iterable, key) {
  for(let i of iterable) {
    yield i;
    if((iterable instanceof Map && i[0] === key) || i === key)
      return;
  }
}

// Same as iterTo, but starts at the key and goes all the way to the end
function* iterFrom(iterable, key) {
  let found = false;
  for(let i of iterable) {
    if(found = (found || (iterable instanceof Map && i[0] === key) || i === key))
      yield i;
  }
}

// reverseIter creates a reverse facade for iterable
function* reverseIter(iterable) {
  let all = [...iterable];
  for(let i = all.length; i--; )
    yield all[i];
}
```

You can then use and compound like this:

```
let m = new Map();
m.set(1, 'a');
m.set(2, 'b');
m.set(3, 'c');
m.set(4, 'd');
m.set(5, 'e');

let s = new Set();
s.add(100);
s.add(200);
s.add(300);
s.add(400);


console.log(...iterTo(m, 3), ...iterFrom(m, 3));
console.log(...reverseIter(iterTo(m, 3)), ...reverseIter(iterFrom(m, 3)));

console.log(...reverseIter(iterTo(s, 200)));
```

Comment: @Bergi - any suggestions?

Comment: None really - `Map`s and `Set`s just don't provide an API for backward or partial iteration. If you really have to do that, I guess converting to an array and using `slice` would be more efficient.

Comment: Btw, that `|=` operator looks like a mistake. Better write it out than using bitwise integer operators on booleans.

Comment: @Bergi - took your point regarding the if condition - it's a bit more readable like that. regarding `slice`, I don't see how that makes it more efficient, the function should still `yield` the values so what's the point of slicing first?

Answer (score 1):

What you probably want is a `slice` of the `keys` from the first element to the index of the `key`, reverse that, iterate over that and get the values from the map.

I am assuming your `map` is an object:

```
let keys = Object.keys(map);
return keys.slice(0, keys.indexOf('key')).map((k) => map[k]);
```

You don't really need a generator.

Comment: `Object.keys()` won't get a [`Map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) keys at all. If anything `Map.prototype.keys()` will, but I don't see how that helps preventing iterating the entire Map entries.

Comment: Shame on me for not knowing the existence of Map in ES6 :/