# In ES6, there is iterator.next(); is there any way to supply iterator.previous()?

Tags: javascript, set, ecmascript-6

Going through the full ES6 [Compatibility table](https://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es6/).  Just got on to `Set()`.

```
const set = new Set();
set.add('foo');
set.add('baz');

const iterator = set.values();
iterator.next(); // { value: "foo", done: false }
iterator.next(); // { value: "baz", done: false }
```

Is it possible to write a method similar to `iterator.next()`, but it iterates backwards instead of forwards (i.e. `iterator.previous()`)?

Comment: possible duplicate of [ES6 reverse iterate an array using for..of](http://stackoverflow.com/q/32444463/1048572) or [es6 map/set iterate backwards](http://stackoverflow.com/q/32498034/1048572)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `values()` returns an iterator object and it is not possible to iterate them backwards, because JavaScript iterator objects could be infinite. For example, consider this

```
function * Counter() {
    "use strict";
    var i = 0;
    while (1) {
        yield i++;
    }
}
```

Now, you can create an iterator with `Counter()` and that will never end. So going backwards is not an option with iterators, generally.

---

If you badly need something like backIterator, then you have to maintain  the values produced by the iterator and then move back and forth based on the `next` calls.

Comment: Logically, you can’t start iterating at the end of an infinite set of elements. However, it is false to say that this makes it impossible for iterators to be iterated backwards. For a demonstration, see my answer.

Comment: @kleinfreund I am sure you didn't get through the last paragraph.

Comment: @kleinfreund Okay, Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Although you can’t provide a `previous()` method to iterators similar to the `next()` method at this time, the other answers are not correct. You can iterate backwards over any iterable with the ES [iteration protocol](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Iteration_protocols) by changing the `next()` method of the iterator.

The real culprit is that **you need to decide whether you want to iterate forwards *or* backwards**. Currently, you can’t do both at the same time because you have to override the `next()` method in the iterator to have it work backwards.

Continuing your example with the `Set` object, you can override the `values()` method and provide your own iterable iterator like this:

```
const set = new Set();
set.add('foo');
set.add('baz');

const iterator = set.values();
console.log(iterator.next()); // { value: "foo", done: false }
console.log(iterator.next()); // { value: "baz", done: false }

set.values = function () {
  const reversedContents = Array.from(this);
  return {
    [Symbol.iterator]() {
      return this;
    },
    next() {
      const isDone = reversedContents.length === 0;
      return {
        value: reversedContents.pop(),
        done: isDone
      };
    }
  };
}

const reverseIterator = set.values();
console.log(reverseIterator.next()); // { value: "baz", done: false }
console.log(reverseIterator.next()); // { value: "foo", done: false }
```

This is not ideal as this creates an array out of the set in order to obtain the last element from the set.

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing to stop you doing this, for example below by wrapping a `Set`.

You obviously won't be able to iterate over `previous()` directly, but you could call it manually, or simply switch direction with a call to `previous()`, and next now iterates in reverse.

```
values() {
  const items = [...set.values()];
  let index = -1;

  return {
    [Symbol.iterator]() {
      return this;
    },

    next() {
      var item = items[index + 1];
      if (item) {
        return {
          value: item,
          done: false
        };
      }
      return { done: true };
    },

    previous() {
      var item = items[index - 1];
      if (item) {
        return {
          value: item,
          done: false
        };
      }
      return { done: true };
    }
  };
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I'm afraid there's no JS method to do that, however nobody stops you from saving the previous value in a variable and reading from it.

Comment: How many previous value would need to be stored in the variables? Or separate duplicate array/iterator?